# Debian ограничение доступа

Tags: debian

Как для нового пользователя с доступом /bin/bash ограничить запуск команд? К примеру запретить выполнение любых всех команд кроме команды top. Так же там есть пару команд, для которых есть параметры. Но лучшим вариантом будет запереть пользователя в своей папке и разрешить пару системных команд. Как так лучше всего сделать?

Comment: Поставить ему top в качестве шелла (через chsh, например)

Comment: Для более общего случая подойдёт rbash и PATH, указывающий в нужное место.

Comment: Так же там есть пару команд, для которых есть параметры. Но лучшим вариантом будет запереть пользователя в своей папке и разрешить пару системных команд. Как так лучше всего сделать?

Comment: Никак, надёжного варианта не существует. Лучше организовать работу так, чтобы запуск любых команд был безвреден.

Comment: В чем страхи? Если пользователь не имеет доступа к рутовому аккаунту и если вы не мудрили с базовыми превилегиями на системные каталоги - системная целостность не страдает